# Openvpn routing to client local subnet timeout

Tags: openvpn

This is the current network i have. From client pc, i want to reach the client subnet

[image: Current network]

My Server Openvpn is part of my Asus router RT-AC86U with a merlin firmware
[image]

then in /jffs/configs/openvpn/ccd i have a file for the client pikb400

```
iroute 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

my clients have the following :

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote XXXXXXX 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
float
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC:AES-128-CBC
keepalive 15 60
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/auth.txt
remote-cert-tls server
```

From client pc, when i check the route taken to 192.168.1.254 i get this

```
$ tracert 192.168.1.254

Tracing route to 192.168.1.254 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    46 ms    47 ms    49 ms  10.8.0.3
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

It's almost as if it is stuck on my pikb400 client ? . None of the vpn client have a firewall and i ran `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` on pikb400 client

Comment: as I understand this is not a business environment or relationship to. please flag the question for movement to superuser.com where it might be on topic on due serverfault.com is for business purposes only

Comment: thank you, i will remember next time. FYI i answered my question, i had to add some iptable rules to forward traffix from the tun interface to the other as per https://arashmilani.com/post?id=53

Comment: why beeing rude to me? You did not read -> [what Topics can I ask about here](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Add the Complete answer below your question and Accept it.

Comment: i didn't mean to be rude sorry

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem, i had to add some iptable rules to forward traffic from the tun interface to the other as per http://arashmilani.com/post?id=53

Comment: Please remind, to accept your own answer after 24hour else we will keeped reminded until the end of the universe or site existings - depends what gets the first effect. :D